# Play framework 2 i18n use of space in conf file

Tags: internationalization, playframework-2.0

How can I have spaces in the conf file, they are automaticlly trimmed. How can I force the framework to keep it.

I tried using `&nbsp;` but it prints out `&nbsp;` and not the space!

in messages.fr I have

```
"mykey.range= à "
```

result in `"à"` (trimmed)

and

```
"myKey.range=&nbsp;à&nbsp;"
```

result in `"&nbsp;à&nbsp;"` !!!!

I tried "\" before the &. Didn't work... I gave up and asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single-quotes around the value to force it to keep your spaces.

**conf/messages**

```
mykey.range=' à '
```

Alternatively, I believe that you could use `&nbsp;` as you tried but then in your template you would need to tell Play to interpret that text as HTML.

```
@Html(Messages("mykey.range"))
```

Comment: @guillaume-bois I edited my answer... it's single-quotes not double